# Android 6.0 build error - sap-api.pb.h

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, cyanogenmod

I'm getting the following error while building Android ROM, either it is AOSP/CyanogenMod

```
In file included from hardware/ril-caf/libril/RilSapSocket.cpp:21:0:
hardware/ril-caf/libril/RilSapSocket.h:22:55: fatal error: hardware/ril/librilutils/proto/sap-api.pb.h: No such file or directory
 #include <hardware/ril/librilutils/proto/sap-api.pb.h>
                                                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

When I look into the path in github.com/CyanogenMod and github.com/Android I couldn't find sap-api.pb.h
What could be the problem and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error message, and I tried to find the generated file with `find` command:

```
$ find . -name "sap-api.pb.h"
./out/target/product/bacon/gen/STATIC_LIBRARIES/librilutils_static_intermediates/proto/hardware/ril-caf/librilutils/proto/sap-api.pb.h
./out/target/product/bacon/gen/SHARED_LIBRARIES/librilutils_intermediates/proto/hardware/ril-caf/librilutils/proto/sap-api.pb.h
```

then I notice the `#include` path is a bit different from the real path, I open the error `.h` file and change `hardware/ril/...` to `hardware/ril-caf/...` in these two files:

- `hardware/ril-caf/libril/rilSocketQueue.h`
- `hardware/ril-caf/libril/RilSapSocket.h`

Then, the build passed.

Hope this help.